# Update Data With Entry() Method In EF core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have editing data with entry method in ef core inside an async method.
but when the program reaches the entry method throws an exception.
exception message :

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type
>   'clinicSpecifications' cannot be  tracked because another instance
>   with the same key value for {'clinicSpecificationsID'} is already 
>   being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key  value is attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the 
>   conflicting key values.'

this is my action:

```cs
[HttpPost("updateClinicSpecifications")]
public async Task<IActionResult> updateData(clinicSpecifications clinicSpecificationsParam, clinicOpeningHours clinicOpeningHoursParam)
{
    if (clinicSpecificationsParam.isActive == true)
    {
        await ClinicSpecificationsRepository.disableAllClinicAddress();

        //update AllAddress To Disable this update working correctly

        await ClinicSpecificationsRepository.saveChanges();
    }

    clinicSpecificationsParam.createDate = DateTime.Now.toShamsi();
    clinicOpeningHoursParam.createDate = DateTime.Now.toShamsi();

    //but when program reaches to this update exception is throws

    bool result = await ClinicSpecificationsRepository.editclinicSpecifications(clinicSpecificationsParam);

    bool result2 = await ClinicOpeningHoursRepository.editClinicOpeningHours(clinicOpeningHoursParam);

    if (result == true)
    {
        await ClinicSpecificationsRepository.saveChanges();
    }

    if (result2 == true)
    {
        await ClinicOpeningHoursRepository.saveChanges();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

this is disableAllClinicAddress method :

```cs
public async Task disableAllClinicAddress()
{
    var allAddress = await getAllClinicSpecifications();

    foreach (var item in allAddress)
    {
        item.isActive = false;
        await editclinicSpecifications(item);
    }
}
```

and my update method :

```cs
public async Task<bool> editclinicSpecifications(clinicSpecifications clinicSpecifications)
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() => db.Entry(clinicSpecifications).State = EntityState.Modified);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

please help me thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have editing data with entry method in ef core inside an async method. but when the program reaches the entry method throws an exception. exception message

Because you're creating a new instance (which isn't tracked) instead of updating the existing instance (which is tracked).Change like below:

```
var clinicSpecificationsParam = _dbcontext.clinicSpecifications.Find(id);
```

Here is a working demo I tested:

1.Model:

```
public class clinicSpecifications
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime createDate { get; set; }
}
```

2.Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly YourContext _context;

    public HomeController(YourContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [HttpPost("updateClinicSpecifications")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> updateData(int id)
    {
        var clinicSpecificationsParam = _context.clinicSpecifications.Find(id);
        if (clinicSpecificationsParam.isActive == true)
        {
            await disableAllClinicAddress();

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        clinicSpecificationsParam.createDate = DateTime.Now;

        bool result = await editclinicSpecifications(clinicSpecificationsParam);
        //...
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    public async Task disableAllClinicAddress()
    {
        var allAddress = _context.clinicSpecifications.ToList();

        foreach (var item in allAddress)
        {
            item.isActive = false;
            await editclinicSpecifications(item);
        }
    }
    public async Task<bool> editclinicSpecifications(clinicSpecifications clinicSpecifications)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => _context.Entry(clinicSpecifications).State = EntityState.Modified);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

3.DbContext:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public YourContext (DbContextOptions<YourContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<clinicSpecifications> clinicSpecifications { get; set; }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Why my editing method doesn't work without finding the clinic by ID?
Do not find the entry method in ef core record automatically?

Comment: Yes.As my said initially,what you did is creating a new instance.When you pass the model to edit method,EF Core would not find the record in your database automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In your update method, avoid using EntityState.Modified. I know it's a valid command but you can see you are having issues. You must first track the entry in question by doing a find or firstordefault to collect the record. Then you can modify the record and resave it. Here's some code off the top of my head but not tested.

```
var entry = db.ClinicSpecifications.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id);
entry.Field = clinicSpecification.Field;
db.SaveChanges();
```

Again a rough example, but it works flawlessly.

Comment: Thank you so much
But I have a question:
If I delete all async and wait for my code
And overwrite my methods without async / await
Will my problem be resolved inside the update method?

Comment: If your async code is broken, yes, but if not no. Entity is a bit of a tricky beast when you start working with it. I used to write all my code free of async methods and then added it later. But as time goes on, you'll find that it becomes nature to add it in on the fly. Hope that helps.